# Showing dependency relationships in Docker Registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

#### Summary

How can we graph or otherwise get an overview of Docker image dependency relationships in the Docker registry?

#### Details

We're using a private [docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) instance to locally host some Docker images. We have images depending on other images (via `FROM`) for example:

```
sun-java8-build -> tomcat -> our_app
```

which is quite simple but it is easy for images to quickly depend on quite a few underlying "base images". How can we get an overview of which images are used to build up further images? This will help understand the impact of changes to various base images.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion dependencies should be defined using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) rather than wrapping an image in an image in an image and so on.

> Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker
>   applications.